# Is this possible(pythagorean triples)

Tags: geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

My maths teacher gave me some problems and one of them was that I have a right triangle with side 6 and area 30.. So my questions are: 1.Is this even possible and 2.should I assume that most of the time, a right triangle with side 6 would be egyptian (pythagorean triple)
P.S sorry if my sentence formation isn't top tier..

Comment: Yes, one leg is 6, so take the other side as 10 so the area is 30. I don't see why not. Unless the sides have to be integers (?)

Comment: Im not restricted to integers, but thought it would be something easier  since the other problems from the list were super easy..

Comment: @sedrick Also, thanks!

Comment: The only Pythagorean triple (integer sides required) with an area of $30$ is $(5,12,13)$. The only right triangle with one side of $6$ and an area of  $30$ is $(6,10,11.66190379)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. The side of length 6 is a cathetus (adjacent to right angle):  As the area is $30 = \frac12 c\cdot6$ where $c$ is the length of the other cathetus, there must be $c=10$.
2. The side of length 6 is the hypothenuse (opposite of right angle): The area is $30=\frac12h\cdot6$ where $h$ is the height of the triangle, thus $h = 10$.  Moreover, as it is a right triangle, the right angle is at [Thales' circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) which has radius $6/2 = 3$ around the middle of the hypothenuse.  As this circle does not intersect a line that is $h=10$ units away from the hypothenuse and parallel to it, no solutions from this case.